# Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-webjobs

I am doing the webjobs using ASP.NET Core. I'm not able to set the dependency injection properly.

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
            var host = BuildHost(args);

            using (host)
            {
                await host.RunAsync();
            }
    }


    public static IHost BuildHost(string[] args) =>
new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureHostConfiguration(builder => 
    {
        builder
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
    {
        b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
        b.AddAzureStorage();
        b.AddTimers();
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddScoped<ISchedularService, SchedularService>();
        //services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, PrintTimeService>()
    }).Build();
```

And in the functions.cs file, I have accessed the scheduler service in the constructor. but it didn't fire the constructor and throws an exception like:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

```
public class Functions
{

    private readonly ISchedularService _schedularService;
    public Functions(SchedularService schedularService)
    {
        _schedularService = schedularService;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the answer works for you, could you please help mark it as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you're using the latest packages. I used your code with latest packages, and it works well.

I didn't use the async method.

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var host = BuildHost(args);

            using (host)
            {
                 host.Run();
            }           
        }

        public static IHost BuildHost(string[] args) =>
            new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureHostConfiguration(builder =>
            {
                builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
                b.AddAzureStorage();
                b.AddTimers();
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddScoped<IWebJobConfiguration,WebJobConfiguration>();
            })
            .Build();
```

In Functions.cs:

```
        private readonly IWebJobConfiguration _webJobConfiguration;
        public Functions(IWebJobConfiguration webJobConfiguration)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("*** DI via constructor ***");
            _webJobConfiguration = webJobConfiguration;
        }

        public void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue111")] string message, ILogger logger)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_webJobConfiguration.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(message + ";consoleqqqq");
        }
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

DependencyInjection problems generally occur when the wrong interface added to services. I encountered a similar problem and my code just works in .Net Core 2.x and does not work on .Net Core 3.x. 
Probably there are more controls in interfaces in 3.x.
Those 2 same injections work together in 2.x but not in 3.x

```
        services.AddScoped<IHttpClientFactory, HttpClientFactory>();

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpClientFactory>(new HttpClientFactory(
            Configuration["PortalLogin:Adress"],
            LoginApiUserName,
            LoginApiPassword));
```